# Is evolution a lie according to Islam?

Tags: science, evolution

according to Islam philosophy, Allah created humans and sent them to earth but science says that humans [evolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_human_evolution) from primates... We also have the proof of early humans ([Neanderthals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal) and [Homo erectus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_erectus)).

1. Does that mean these creatures are seperate from us and existed before us?
2. Is this where Islam and Science contradict each other?
3. Is there any explanation which can resolve the said contradiction?
4. Is evolution a lie according to islam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question was asked before and I remember reading a great answer, but since I cannot find it I will simply summarise it according to what I remember:
Essentially, it could be a lie or it could be the truth depending on how we view creation.
If Allah simply created us as homo Sapians and created everything else the way they are now, then yes evolution is a lie.
But if Allah created us through steps, such as how evolution works, then we can argue that evolution is not a farce.
It all depends on how you believe or view creation works, some people support the former and some argue the latter, it is for you to study, research and find which you want to believe in.